# How to convert string into datetime value using Azure Data Factory Data Flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a TransactionDate column in csv file like **3/14/2021  7:24:00 PM** & **3/14/2021  9:10:00 AM**.
when i use dataflows in ADF and connect to **source .csv** file **i see in projection Transactiondate column type as string**. I added **filter transformation** & in data preview **i see values in TransactionDate column as 3/14/2021 19:24 & 3/14/2021 9:10**.

**How can i convert the values of TransactionDate  column into 2021/03/14 19:24:00:000 & 2021/03/14 09:10:00:000**